# Any PHP svn GUI with commit functionally

Tags: php, svn, user-interface, git-svn

I have seen a few that only have the checkout functions and options to view the `diff` and revisions but none with the option to `commit` changes, so my question:

**Any PHP svn GUI with commit functionally?**

### Update:

to simplify even more:

i need a browser-based interface to a SVN repo that supports write operations, do you know of any?

Comment: What do you mean by "PHP svn GUI"? A gui written in PHP? Why in PHP?

Comment: Mmm, interesting question, although the answer may well be "no, at least not for free". I have never seen one

Comment: @KingCrunch I assume he means a browser-based interface to a SVN repo that supports write operations, and is written in PHP.

Comment: @KingCrunch yeah the main idea is  _browser-based interface to a SVN repo that supports write operations, and is written in PHP._

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reason one doesn't exist is because it'd be clumsy to use.

You wouldn't have direct file system access (I don't think even Flash or Silverlight provide that, but I could be wrong), so you'd need to upload the files you want to commit or diff.

If you're not using any browser plugins you'd be further limited to uploading a single file at a time, which isn't the way SVN is meant to work.  You commit a whole changeset, not one file at a time.

The only feasible way to do this I guess is to have your working copy also on the server and do your editing in the browser as well.  At which point though you're not looking for just a web SVN GUI, you're looking for a web-based IDE that has SVN support.

--Edit--

The closest I've been able to find is this http://kodingen.com/ which is still in beta, and looks like it plans to have SVN support but it's not currently available in the beta version (at the time of this answer)

Comment: I'm thinking more in the lines of i check out a repo edit the files online and then commit!